# Having problems while trying to remove inflated views of each row of a custom todo list through a checkbox?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-studio

I am populating a listview through an editable text, the listview is custom made and each row contains a textview and a checkbox, for now I want each rows inflated view to be removed by clicking the checkboxes and deleting them through the delete button but how can I manipulate `values.get(position)` with `todoCheckBox.isChecked()` so that I would be able to remove each positions, and secondly how can I remove inflated views of each row previously I had done `values.remove(positions)` but that only removed elements from the arraylist and `todoTextView.setText(“”)` only changed the text of the textview but the view of the row was still there.

Please keep in mind that I’m a beginner here . . .

```
public class todoFragment extends ListFragment{

private EditText mToDoField;
private Button mAdd;
private Button mDelete;
UsersAdapter mAdapter;
private TextView todoTextView;
private CheckBox todoCheckBox;
ListView listViewToDo;
String val;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getActivity().setTitle(R.string.todo_title);
}

public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

public Context context;
public ArrayList<String> values;

public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
    super(context, 0, values);

    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_list, parent, false);

    todoTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.todo_TextView);
    todoCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.todo_CheckBox);

    todoTextView.setText(values.get(position));

    todoCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          //Toast.makeText(getContext(), " CheckBox Status: " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          if (todoCheckBox.isChecked()){

              val = "true";
              values.get(position).contains(val);
          }


          mDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {

                  if (mDelete.isPressed() && (values.get(position).contains(val))){

                     //convertView.clearFocus(position);

                      todoTextView.setText("");

                  }
              }
          });


      }
     });

    return convertView;
}
}



@TargetApi(9) // remember this for isEmpty()
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo, container, false);

ArrayList<String> todoList = new ArrayList<String>();
mAdapter = new UsersAdapter(getActivity(), todoList);
listViewToDo = (ListView) v.findViewById (android.R.id.list);
listViewToDo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

mToDoField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.todo_editText);
mDelete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);

mAdd = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        String toDo = mToDoField.getText().toString().trim();

        if (toDo.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }

        mAdapter.add(toDo);

        mToDoField.setText("");
    }
});

return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

keep your `values.remove(positions)` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter